# Wrong console output and template not rendering

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

In the output of `console.log` an undefined is added `pre` to the `img` tag.
secondly the `index ejs` template is also not rendering.

```
app.set("view engine" , "ejs");
app.get('/', async ()=>
{
    let cont =  await data.find();
    let htmlContent;
    for(let x=0;x<cont.length;x++)
     htmlContent += `<img="${cont[0].image}"/><br> <p>${cont[0].content</p>`;
    console.log(htmlContent);
    app.render('index', {renderData:htmlContent});
} );
```

**Output i want:**

```
<img="sdlkfj"/><br><p>sdgdsfgfdshfd</p>
```

**Output i am getting:**

```
undefined<img="sdlkfj"/><br><p>sdgdsfgfdshfd</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`htmlContent` is undefined, then you add a string to it. Try using `let htmlContent = "";` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `cont.length` but using `cont[0]`. So it will be, `cont[x]`

```
for(let x=0;x<cont.length;x++)
     htmlContent += `<img="${cont[x].image}"/><br> <p>${cont[x].content</p>`
```